# how to route to the configuration page for specific module?

Tags: magento2

i am facing a route in my action attribute this url 'adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/Mymodule' but i have no idea for what is this separately or where they have declared it, for example what is this action value means :

```
 <add id="Vendor_Module::resource_config"
             title="Configuration"
             module="Vendor_Module"
             parent="Vendor_Module::resource"
             resource="Vendor_Module::resource_config"
             action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/Mymodule"
        />
```

what does (action="adminhtml/system_config/edit/section/Mymodule") means?

Comment: can you put some screenshots or code for errors you are facing ?

Comment: yes of course  !